# Using R to paste text between specific lines/words in text file?

Tags: r, paste

Say I have got a text file that contains this text:

```
1 ETA BY ibr1*(l_1);
2 ETA BY ibr2*(l_2);
3 ETA BY ibr4*(l_3);
4 ETA BY ibr5*(l_4);
5 ETA BY ibr7*(l_5);
6 ETA BY ibr10*(l_6);
7 ETA BY ibr13*(l_7);
8 ETA ON AGE;
9 ibr1 on AGE;
```

And I would like to use R to append a chunk of text to this file to get this:

```
1 ETA BY ibr1*(l_1);
2 ETA BY ibr2*(l_2);
3 ETA BY ibr4*(l_3);
4 ETA BY ibr5*(l_4);
5 ETA BY ibr7*(l_5);
6 ETA BY ibr10*(l_6);
7 ETA BY ibr13*(l_7);
8 [ibr1$1-ibr1$8];
9 [ibr2$1-ibr2$4];
10 [ibr4$1-ibr4$8];
11 [ibr5$1-ibr5$8];
12 [ibr7$1-ibr7$8];
13 [ibr10$1-ibr10$1];
14 [ibr13$1-ibr13$8];"
15 ETA ON AGE;
16 ibr1 on AGE;
```

I know how to do it this way:

```
line <- "[ibr1$1-ibr1$8];
[ibr2$1-ibr2$4];
[ibr4$1-ibr4$8];
[ibr5$1-ibr5$8];
[ibr7$1-ibr7$8];
[ibr10$1-ibr10$1];
[ibr13$1-ibr13$8];"

sample_text <- readLines("text.inp")
sample_text <- c(sample_text[1:7], line, sample_text[8:9])
writeLines(sample_text, "text.inp")
```

However, I would like to do this by referencing the contents of the text, rather than the line numbers. Specifically, would like to be able to append my chunk of text between the lines that read "ETA BY ibr13*(l_7);" and "ETA ON AGE;". How would I do this? Thank you.

Comment: any special reason to use R instead of bash?

Comment: I am using R to automate the running of several Mplus scripts (and the text file example above is in reference to my Mplus scripts that I am also trying to edit from R).

Comment: Working with R and Mplus, I strongly recommend you to use `MplusAutomation`  package. See tutorial [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MplusAutomation/vignettes/vignette.html) and package documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MplusAutomation/MplusAutomation.pdf)

Comment: Yes, it's a great package. However, it doesn't do what I'm trying to accomplish in my question @RuamPimentel

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input shown in the Note at the end and assuming the result should be a single newline-separated string use `append`.

```
ix <- grep("ETA ON AGE", sample_text) - 1
p <- paste(append(sample_text, line, ix), collapse = "\n")
```

giving

```
> cat(p, "\n")
1 ETA BY ibr1*(l_1);
2 ETA BY ibr2*(l_2);
3 ETA BY ibr4*(l_3);
4 ETA BY ibr5*(l_4);
5 ETA BY ibr7*(l_5);
6 ETA BY ibr10*(l_6);
7 ETA BY ibr13*(l_7);
8 [ibr1$1-ibr1$8];
9 [ibr2$1-ibr2$4];
10 [ibr4$1-ibr4$8];
11 [ibr5$1-ibr5$8];
12 [ibr7$1-ibr7$8];
13 [ibr10$1-ibr10$1];
14 [ibr13$1-ibr13$8];
[ibr1$1-ibr1$8];
[ibr2$1-ibr2$4];
[ibr4$1-ibr4$8];
[ibr5$1-ibr5$8];
[ibr7$1-ibr7$8];
[ibr10$1-ibr10$1];
[ibr13$1-ibr13$8];
15 ETA ON AGE;
16 ibr1 on AGE;
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "1 ETA BY ibr1*(l_1);
2 ETA BY ibr2*(l_2);
3 ETA BY ibr4*(l_3);
4 ETA BY ibr5*(l_4);
5 ETA BY ibr7*(l_5);
6 ETA BY ibr10*(l_6);
7 ETA BY ibr13*(l_7);
8 [ibr1$1-ibr1$8];
9 [ibr2$1-ibr2$4];
10 [ibr4$1-ibr4$8];
11 [ibr5$1-ibr5$8];
12 [ibr7$1-ibr7$8];
13 [ibr10$1-ibr10$1];
14 [ibr13$1-ibr13$8];
15 ETA ON AGE;
16 ibr1 on AGE;"
sample_text <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))

line <- "[ibr1$1-ibr1$8];
[ibr2$1-ibr2$4];
[ibr4$1-ibr4$8];
[ibr5$1-ibr5$8];
[ibr7$1-ibr7$8];
[ibr10$1-ibr10$1];
[ibr13$1-ibr13$8];"
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. Strangely, when I do grep("ETA BY IBR13*(l7);", sample.text") instead of grep("ETA ON AGE", sample_text), it doesn't give me the row index. Do you have any idea of why this might be? EDIT: Nevermind, it's all good thanks.

Comment: *, ( and ) have special menaing in regular expressions.  Use `grep(..., fixed = TRUE)` to remove their special meaning.